# How can this global class variable be pep8 compliant and still work?

Tags: python, class, variables, pep8

[Pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) advises to always use `cls` as the first argument of a class method definition.
Now suppose I want to use a class variable(in this case: `cls.cartridge_state`) that can also be used in an instance method (in this case: `__init__`). So for that I need to make the variable global(see code below). But instantiating `FountainPen` generates the following runtime error:

```
self.cartridge_state = cls.cartridge_state
NameError: global name 'cls' is not defined
```

But then again when I change `global cartridge_state` into `global cls.cartridge_state` I get a syntaxError when i try to import the module.

```
class FountainPen(object):
    cartridge_ink = "water-based"
    @classmethod
    def toggle_default_cartridge_state(cls):
        i = 0
        cartridge_states = ['non-empty','empty']
        global cartridge_state
        cls.cartridge_state = cartridge_states[i]
        i += 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.cartridge_state = cls.cartridge_state
        global number_of_refills
        self.number_of_refills = 0

    def write(self):
        print Pen.write(self)
        self.cartridge_state = "empty"
        return self.cartridge_state

    def refill(self):
        self.cartridge_state = "non-empty"
        self.number_of_refills += 1
```

How can I let the class variable `cartridge_state` be pep8 compliant and make this code work without errors?

Comment: This seems like a messy and over complicated design

Comment: `global cartridge_state` is a no-op in your code, I think. `cls.cartridge_state` is certainly a different identifier.

Comment: Also, `toggle_default_cartridge_state` won't do what you think it does; it'll *always* set `cls.cartridge_state` to `'non-empty'`.

Comment: You don't need or want globals to do what you are trying to do. Address the class by name to access class variables if you are not in a class method - `FountainPen.cartridge_state`. And as Martijn points out, `i` is not persisted between calls to `toggle_default_cartridge_state()`.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: it is messy, but the point is to experiment how class variables behave, how global can be used in a class environment, how class variables can be assigned to instance variables etc.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Indeed, `toggle_default_cartridge_state` will just always set to `'non-empty'`. How would you implement this toggle functionality without resorting to flat files or databases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class attribute can be read via `self`:

```
class FountainPen(object):
    cartridge_ink = "water-based"
    default_cartridge_state = "empty"

    @classmethod
    def toggle_default_cartridge_state(cls):
        if cls.default_cartridge_state == "empty":
            cls.default_cartridge_state = "non-empty"  
        else:
            cls.default_cartridge_state = "empty"

    def __init__(self):
        self.cartridge_state = self.default_cartridge_state

    def write(self):
        print Pen.write(self)
        self.cartridge_state = "empty"
        return self.cartridge_state

    def refill(self):
        self.cartridge_state = "non-empty"
        self.number_of_refills += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What `PEP 8` says is that `cls` should be the first argument. The same way when you define the first argument `self` in instance methods. I suppose this is for avoiding troubles when you call a class method like this `self.yourclassmethod()`. But I can't see why it is necessary having the `@classmethod` decorator.

**EDIT:**

I do it differently, instead of `@classmethod` I use `@staticmethod` but I realize we are not talking about the same thing. If someone believes I am wrong please tell me.

Example:

```
class Bar(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foo(myarg):
        return myarg * 2

Bar.foo(2)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I correct myself, `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` represent different things (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)). A static method shouldn't be modifying variables from the class.

Comment: I'll come back to that later, at some point of this exercice I was going to use `@staticmethod` instead of `@classmethod` to see what was the difference.

Comment: Basically a `@staticmethod` is useful to append a function to your class, `self` is not passed in this case. It acts like a module function.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `global`; `global` has nothing to do with classes and objects.

When you access a property on an object, it will be looked up first on the object and then on the class.  That means that if you want an object to have its own copy of a property and not reflect subsequent updates to that property on the class, all you need to do is copy it in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.prop = self.prop
```

Comment: I am trying to find out the behaviour of `global` on class variables. `global` CAN be used on a class variable. So saying "global has nothing to do with classes and objects" I would not deem correct. It can't be called without an instance or class, so it's behaviour is at least different from global on a 'regular' variable. But it is likely redundant, I haven't even come to evaluating that, merely how it works and if it works. 
I was trying to assign a class variable to an instance variables. For the time being I don't see any other way to do that unless using `global`.

Comment: K srry, I understand now from Ned Batchelder's example what you were trying to explain and that the same behaviour can be done without global. I'm sorry I couldn't tell from your example.